# How to convert String to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have string that I received whenever there is new remote notifications.I'm using parse for my Backend. And String that I retrieved come from "createdAt" column.

I've tried below code:

```
    var ca = "2015-07-03T03:16:17.220Z"
    var dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    let date = dateFormater.dateFromString(ca)

    println(date)
```

But the println is giving me nil, I think there is something wrong with my date format. How can I fix this?

Comment: That looks like an ISO 8601 date. You may want to just use Peter Hosey's [open source and widely used ISO 8601 date formatter](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter)

Comment: See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the milliseconds. Thus:

```
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Note, when converting from the date string to a `NSDate`, you shouldn't quote the `Z`. If you quote the `Z`, it will match the literal `Z` character, but won't correctly reflect that this date string is actually Zulu/GMT/UTC.

---

If you want to create formatter that also goes the other way, converting `NSDate` objects to strings, in that case you should quote the `Z`, but in that case you must remember to explicitly set the timezone:

```
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```

---

By the way, don't forget to set the `locale` as per [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

```
dateFormater.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: OK, so a Z without an offset defaults to GMT, I did not realize that.

Comment: Yep, an unquoted capital `Z` (per the [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) you shared with us) instructs the formatter to parse the timezone out of the string. And when it encounters a `Z` in the date string (not to be confused with the `Z` in the formatter string), it correctly parses recognizes that as GMT/UTC. It's a tad more flexible than using literal `Z` in the formatter string.